# (Flutter) Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset

Tags: flutter

I just had to register here now. I no longer understand the world! I have now even set up Flutter and the whole project again, but I always get the following error message:

**Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: "assets/images/IMG_8231.jpeg".**

I don't know where the damn problem is^^
Does anyone have any ideas? What am I not seeing? Thank you!

[Code and folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnIOt.png)
[pubspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl1iO.png)

I checked the folder structure, the file names, the code. I even rebuilt the project. I did "flutter get pub". After flutter run again:

Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/IMG_8231.jpeg")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#11678(), name:
"assets/images/IMG_8231.jpeg", scale: 1.0)

and **Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: "assets/images/IMG_8231.jpeg".**

Comment: first please re run the apps, don't just hot reload. second, did you run your code on Flutter Web ?